# Solving the functional $\min \int_0^1xy^2+x^3y\;dx$

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations

I'm having a course on Calculus of Variations and I'm doing my first homework problems. One of them is the following:

> Determine the smooth extremum which satisfies the boundary conditions
>   for:
>
> $$\min \int_0^1xy^2+x^3y\;dx,\;\;\;y(0)=A, \;y(1)=B,$$
>
> where $y=y(x)$.

Can someone guide me how to solve this problem correctly? What I tried is the following:

I know that in order for $y^*$ be the optimal solution for the functional, then it must satisfy the Euler-Lagrange equation:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\right)=0,$$

where in my problem $F(x,y,y') = xy^2+x^3y$ and $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$. By applying the E-L equation I get:

$$2xy+x^3=0,$$

from where I solve that $$y=-\frac{1}{2}x^2.$$

Where should I apply the boundary conditions now? Did I make a mistake somewhere or is this how I'm supposed to solve it? Thank you for your help =)

Or does the boundary conditions in this case mean that: $y(0)=A=0 $ and $y(1)=B=-\frac{1}{2}$?

P.S. here is my problem in its original form:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your integrand, $F(x,y,y')$, has no $y'$ dependence?

Comment: Hi @Mattos I think so yes, $y'$ isn't explicitly given in the integrand...I will post the original question to my questions as well so you can verify if I did any mistakes.

Comment: Your work is all correct, yes. Usually when the integrand depends on $y'$, the Euler-Lagrange equation yields a differential equation and you use the initial conditions to solve for the constants of integration. But this is a simpler problem that doesn't require that step.

Comment: Thank you for your help @MattR. appreciate it :) The boundary conditions got me wondering whether I did something wrong

Comment: But one must interpret what happens when $A\neq0$ or $B\neq-1/2$. In this case the functional doesn't have local extremes, i.e. for every function $y=y(x)$ such that $y(0)=A$ and $y(1)=B$ there are smooth variations that make the functional smaller.